# SBT: Exclude module from aggregates or compilation based on Scala version

Tags: scala, sbt

Having a bit of trouble with the following scenario, where one of the sub-modules in the aggregate list is an SBT plugin, but the aggregate project is cross built for 2.10.x and 2.11.x.

The exclusion logic works well in general, except for any command that beings with a `+`. This looks like an SBT bug, as when the following block is triggered with say `+publish`, the compilation and doc generation in the SBT plugin fails for Scala 2.11, but it shouldn't be included in the first place.

Somehow SBT ignores that, and I've failed to find a different solution for said problem.

How can one define either an exclusion filter or module exclusion conditional on the Scala version being 2.10.x in such a way that it doesn't cause problems with `+` commands?

```
lazy val sbtPlugin = (project in file("projectx-sbt"))
  .settings(sharedSettings: _*)
  .settings(
  scalaVersion := "2.10.6",
  publish := {
    CrossVersion.partialVersion(scalaVersion.value).map {
      case (2, scalaMajor) if scalaMajor >= 11 => false
      case _ => true
    }
  },
  publishMavenStyle := false,
  excludeFilter := {
    CrossVersion.partialVersion(scalaVersion.value) match {
      case Some((2, scalaMajor)) if scalaMajor >= 11 => NothingFilter
      case _ => AllPassFilter
    }
  },
  sbtPlugin := true,
  ..
)
```